# cql を編集するのに適した major mode はありますか

Tags: emacs, cassandra

emacs で cql を編集するのに適した major mode のパッケージはありますか？

Comment: 本家(emacs)でも聞いてみました。 http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20781/is-there-major-mode-for-editting-cql

結論は、それ専用のものはなさそうである、とのことでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

既存では存在しないようなので、自作を始めました。 -> [cql-mode](https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/cql-mode)

Answer (score 0):

sql mode を使ってみるのはどうですか?

Comment: cql は、 sql とは微妙に文法が異なると思っています。ある程度の代用はできそうですが、できれば、 cql 専用の major mode が、あれば使いたいなぁ、と。。